# onChange em React não funcionando!

Tags: react

Essa função está dando erro dizendo que o `event` é `null`

**evento:**

```
handleChange(event) {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        equipe: {
            ...prevState.equipe,
            nome: event.target.value
        }
    }))
}
```

**input:**

```
<input className={classes.titulo} type='text' 
  value={this.state.equipe.nome} 
  onChange={this.handleChange}>
</input>
```

Comment: se pode mostrar o estado inicial que você criou?

Comment: Testa `onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando se vai alterar um objeto contido no estado de um componente em [react](/questions/tagged/react) eu particularmente gosto de separar as atribuições para não ter o problema de confundir aquilo que é para ser alterado, e os `<input>` coloca-se a propriedade `name` com o nome da mesma chave a ser alterado, e ai o `handleChange` vai ser útil pelo fator dinâmico em seu código, observe que o código de alteração fica muito mais simples fazendo assim:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      equipe: {
        nome: '',
        idade: 0
      }
    }
    this.handleChange = 
      this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    let state = this.state;
    state.equipe[e.target.name]= e.target.value
    this.setState(state);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
        <input type="text"
          name="nome"
          value={this.state.equipe.nome} 
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="text"
          name="idade"
          value={this.state.equipe.idade} 
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

e nesse exemplo coloquei mais uma chave para que você entenda que agora o método vai servir de alteração para outras caixas de texto, sempre lembrando de adicionar o name no `<input>`.

Daria para fazer do seu jeito: sim daria:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      equipe: {
        nome: '',
        idade: 0
      }
    }
    this.handleChange = 
      this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleChange(e) {     
    const inputChange = {[e.target.name]: e.target.value};    
    this.setState(state => ({
      equipe: {
        ...state.equipe,
        ...inputChange
      }
    }))
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</div>
        <input type="text"
          name="nome"
          value={this.state.equipe.nome} 
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input type="text"
          name="idade"
          value={this.state.equipe.idade} 
          onChange={this.handleChange} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Carregando ...</div>
```

Comment: MUITO OBRIGADO!

Comment: Só uma ultima coisa, como faria para caso digitado nada ele não aceita-se e retornasse o nome anterior

Comment: Não entendi a sua pergunta @NatãLopes?

Comment: oq eu estou fazendo é o seguinte uma area de texto editável, porém ela não pode ser vazia, então caso o usuario apague tudo e de enter ele não pode aceitar e voltar com o conteudo anterior

Comment: Isso é um regra sua, voltar o conteúdo anterior se vai ter fazer outra rotina no seu código para verificar isso quando perder o foco. ai precisa abrir outro questionamento, cada questão resolve um determinado problema. OK