# useState no Reactjs?

Tags: react, react-hooks

Estou iniciando em `React` depois de estudar `Javascript` e tentando fazer uma coisa bem simples, que é escrever um nome eu um `input` e aparecer na página.

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
  return (
    <form>
      <h2>Preencha seu Nome</h2>
      <input type="text" />
      <button type="submit">Adicionar Nome</button>
    </form>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Você já chegou a consultar a **[documentação sobre formulários do React](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html)**? Ela ainda não está usando _hooks_, mas como você disse já saber como eles funcionam, pode dar uma ideia de como funciona.

Comment: Vários exemplos, um deles: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/463410/problema-na-l%c3%b3gica-react-n%c3%a3o-calcula/463417#463417

Comment: Outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426304/duvida-sobre-padr%c3%a3o-classe-react/426335#426335

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [onChange em React não funcionando!](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476269/onchange-em-react-n%c3%a3o-funcionando)

Comment: Outro exemplo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/476269/onchange-em-react-n%c3%a3o-funcionando/476273#476273

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ter o efeito esperado e digitar na caixa de texto e mostrar o resultado tem que usar o `useState` para guardar o estado atual e no evento `onChange` do `<input />` alterar esse estado, exemplo minimo:

```js
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{name}</h1>
      <div>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          value={name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Se quiser que isso aparece a partir do evento `onSubmit` de um formulário, precisa envolver dentro de um `tag` `form` os elementos e fazer uma referencia a tag `<h1>` com `useRef()` e a partir do submeter do formulário resgate o valor da variável de estado e enviar por referencia para o `h1`, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const [name, setName] = React.useState('');
  const refH1 = React.useRef();
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    refH1.current.innerHTML = name;
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 ref={refH1}></h1>
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input 
          type="text" 
          value={name}
          onChange={e => setName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button>Enviar</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.9.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.9.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: é exatamento isso que eu estava procurando...na verdade era o onChange que faltava

Comment: e se eu quiser colocar um botão e acionar essa renderizaão somente após o submit?

Comment: @lucas-eugenio1990 eu fiz um segundo exemplo.